# Libraries required for GDI in Mono using xsp

Tags: asp.net, mono, gdi+

Here is the situation.  I am creating some graphics (using GDI+) on an asp page running under mono xsp.  This works great in my development environment as my development environment is running under a GUI, however when I try running it on a GUI-less server, it fails (I am assuming due to the fact that certain libraries which are required for Gnome to run aren't installed).  What libraries, and how would I install them, are required to get GDI code running under Mono on a GUI-less installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the name of the library you want is libgdiplus, though I'm not sure if it has a dependency on X11.

Answer (score 1):

mono's implementation of System.Drawing is build on top of the cairo graphics library. See the mono documentation [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Drawing).